# communication with asmx webservices from php through SOAP extension

Tags: php, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm trying to communicate with a remote webservice, using the direction of some [guides](http://www.sbp-romania.com/Blog/2014/11/05/how-to-call-a-wcf-asmx-web-service-from-php.aspx) I found.

Unfortunately, my code gets `-1` instead of the correct result. 
In this case the result should be result = 328000.

[I tested with WCF test client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2XsH.png)

I don't know what to do next.

```
<?php
$soap = new SoapClient('http://www.auto1.cz/datalink/Landlord.asmx?WSDL');
// parameter 
$param=array("strVIN"=>"TMBJG9NEXH0060808");
$result=$soap->GetSellingPrice($param);
echo ($result->GetSellingPriceResult);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59546227/edit) to include what a "correct result" looks like, as well as the definitions for the methods in the code you've provided. It'll be pretty hard to help you without that info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
problem was using double quotes (") instead single ones (')

`...
$param=array('strVIN'=>'TMBJG9NEXH0060808');
...`

Now it worsk properly.